# Javascript click event handler in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a click event handler in gridsome.
Though it's working well but I get the error like this.
[image]

And the code is like below:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("lingallery_thumbnails_content_elem");
divs[0].classList.add("image-border");
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var self = divs[i];
  if (divs[i].children[0].clientWidth > 160) divs[i].children[0].style.width = "160px";
  divs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var image_border_el = document.getElementsByClassName("image-border")[0];
    image_border_el.classList.remove("image-border");
    divs[i].classList.add("image-border");
    divs[i].children[0].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("click", { bubbles: true, cancelable: false }));
  });
}
```

If you have an idea, please help me.

Comment: I think you are recursively triggering the same event

Comment: Can you explain more about this?
Actually I had to do this because I have to create event handler to every div element.
I inserted this code in mounted().

Comment: `divs[i].children[0].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: false }));` this will the trigger the callback recursively

Comment: Ok, Then how do I have to avoid this?